# Why is Eclipse so slow when debugging Android applications?

Tags: android

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or right, but when I'm debugging my Android app it feels like forever before the emulator launches. At least 30 seconds. Is it normal? Should it take so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 30 seconds, it is good for you. It is normal and depends on machine configuration, eclipse plugins and whole lot. My machine,sometimes it takes 1-2 minutes also.

Comment: Then it's somehow true that java takes forever.

Comment: You get a lot of coffeebreaks when doing android.

Comment: Yeah, lot of coffee breaks, but irritating. I have limited time spending on apps, half-of it goes to idle wait. Anyways that is how it works with eclipse.

Comment: or.. just get a better computer :)

Answer (score 3):

you could keep the emulator running in the background or enable the snapshots.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not to close emulator program after finishing debugging. If you start another debug without closing the emulator, it won't launch again

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts ... stop using the emulator if you like to live many years, look for a hardware device (mobile, tablet, miniPC, whatever), connect it and ...

Enjoy debugging.

And only use the emulator to check very specific issues on Android versions you don't have at hand, knowing you will spend a lot of time waiting.

I have a $65 IMito MX2 connected with an ethernet USB adapter, a VNC server and changed my ADB connection from USB to VNC on Ethernet (don't forget to turn off Wifi because Ethernet and Wifi can't live together on Android) ... and I have a fast window showing me a real Android device with a real CPU, instead of a painfully slow emulator.  The time saved pay the miniPC many times.

I think that part on the Android development experience is far from being perfect.